# Databricks - alter complex data type in hive table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a delta table which is partitioned with below structure in Databricks

```
  |--Name
  |--Group
    |--Computer
    |  |--C
    |  |--Java
    |--Biology
    |--Commerce
  |--Date
```

I am trying to add a new struct field under Group.Computer.

Expected Schema:

```
  |--Name
  |--Group
    |--Computer
    |  |--C
    |  |--Java
    |  |--Python
    |--Biology
    |--Commerce
  |--Date
```

I am trying to do this using below alter command

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> CHANGE COLUMN GROUP GROUP STRUCT<COMPUTER:STRUCT<C:STRING, JAVA:STRING, PYTHON STRING>,BIOLOGY:STRING, COMMERCE:STRING>
```

But i get an error like below:

```
cannot update spark_catalog.table_name field computer type:update a struct by updating its fields;
```

How to alter complex data types of existing table in databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it as a column but using the fully-qualified name in dotted notation - [Databricks SQL doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html) explicitly says about it:

```sql
alter table <TABLE_NAME> add column group.computer.cobol string
```